# Notify users of incoming call without using PushKit and CallKit as it is deactivated in China and I don't want to exclude China Appstore

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, callkit

For my VoIP app how to notify users about incoming calls as CallKit has deactivated in China. Is there any alternative to CallKit that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There's no alternative to CallKit. As far as I know, the only thing you can do is to use normal push notifications to notify an incoming call, as WhatsApp does for video calls even outside the China Appstore.

Comment: Further, How can we notify to user in terminated app like Whatsapp (Firing notification again and again )